# Can hide one o the tabscreen element?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to hide one of the screens from Bottom Tab Navigator in React Native. It is just because I am using nested navigation and child navigator is tab navigator. I have to define the screen but I don't want to make it visible on the screen. What should I do?

Comment: Can you share your code's relevant part? It is very vague what you are asking.

Comment: Could you please check out the answer to the question. I added my codes there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my first navigation stack. After sign in, navigate to 'Main'

```
const navigator = createStackNavigator({ Signup: {
      screen: SignupScreen,
      navigationOptions:{
          headerShown:false
      }, }, Signin: {
    screen: SigninScreen,
    navigationOptions:{
        headerShown:false
    }, }, Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
    navigationOptions:{
        headerShown:false },
}, Main: {
    screen: MainScreen,
    navigationOptions:{
        headerShown:false
    },}, Partner: {
    screen: PartnerScreen,
    navigationOptions:{
        headerShown:false
    }, }, ProjectDetail: {
    screen: ProjectDetail,
    navigationOptions:{
        headerShown:false
    },}, });
```

And here is my Main screen codes.

```
<NavigationContainer style={{ backgroundColor: '#1f1f1f' }}>
    <View style={[styles.container]}>

    </View>
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Project"
      tabBarOptions={{
        activeTintColor: '#ED4C67',
        inactiveTintColor: '#fafafa',
        activeBackgroundColor: '#222',
        inactiveBackgroundColor: '#222',
        showLabel: false,

      }}
      screenProps={{ Username: this.state.Username }} >

      <Tab.Screen
        name='Project'
        component={ProjectScreen}
        style={display="none"}
        options={{
         
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <Icon name='paperclip' color={color} size={size - 4} />
          ),
        }}
      />

      
      <Tab.Screen name="Partner" component={PartnerScreen}
        options={{
          
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <Icon name='users' color={color} size={size - 4} />
          ),
      }}
         />
            
    

    <Tab.Screen name="Investor" component={InvestorScreen}
      options={{
        tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
          <Icon name='bar-chart' color={color} size={size - 4} />
        ),
      }} />

    <Tab.Screen name="ProjectDetail" component={ProjectDetail}
      options={{
        tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
          <Icon name='bar-chart' color={color} size={size - 4} />
        ),
      }} />



    </Tab.Navigator>

  </NavigationContainer>
```

I want to navigate from 'PartnerScreen' to 'ProjectDetail'. But I can't use this.props.navigation.navigate or replace because of the nested navigation rules without a ProjectDetail screen in tabnavigator. So I thought that I can hide it.